# How do I access a setter from two levels up using abstraction + inheritance in Java?

Tags: java, inheritance, abstraction

> Let's say I have a:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public Abstract class A {
private static List<Object> list = new ArrayList<Object>();
public List<Object> getList() {
    return menu;
}

public void setList(List<Object> list) {
    A.List = list;
}
}

public abstract class C extends A {
@Override
public List<Object> getList() {
    return list;
}
@Override
public void setList(List<Object> list) {
    A.list = list;
}
}

Public abstract class B extends A {

// there are some overridden methods which have nothing to do with the 
// list I am having issue with

}

public class E extends C{
static {
       A.menu.add("addItem");
     }    
B(int num) {
super.num = num;
}

// some more codes
}
```

> // finally, here is the base class

```
   public class BaseClass extends C {
   Public static void main(String[] args){
   //  C.method1(); // assume there is no problem, it rans
   //  C.method2(); // same above
   //  C.method3(); // same above, runs no problem

    }
}
```

> ****************  Misc info & my questions **************
> a) class A, B, C are abstract classes
> b) class D, E, BaseClass are concrete classes
>
> also currently>

> [A > B > D && A > C > E && BaseClass] ( '>' means 'extends' )

> c) if I comment out static block in class B, all codes run without any
> issue; if I don't comment out, I get "UnsupportedOperationException"
> exception.

> d) if I use [try catch] clock to catch the exception of the static code, then I > get the same exception, but at least the code runs (this may seems a dumb
> comment to professional programmers; but just wanted to provide as much
> details as possible)

> e) originally there was

```
static {
    menu.add("newItem");
}
```

> now I added [try  catch] to see what's happening; and one more

```
System.out.println("static block is called");
```

> in the [catch] block added some statements to check if it's catching, it
> prints, but seems to be not adding the item.

> In class `[BaseClass]` I created two objects of D, and two objects of class
> E; static block is inside the E to add one more item to the list.

> again if I comment out [the object and it's implementation of Class E]
> inside BaseClass, everything runs smooth.

> if I comment out [the object and method implementation of class D] in class
> BaseClass, code seems to be running

> my only question, how can I make this static block work and add the item to
> the list defined in abstract super class A from

> if said too much, and confused you, please check the picture I attached.

> Thank you in advance.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8wCnr.png)

Comment: How and where are the methods you are trying to call defined?

Comment: Hello @Rick: thank you very much for your reply.